# Is this a proper way of copying a string of char array to 2D array in C?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino, char

I am currently programming an Arduino Uno using C language and I am doing a program that manipulates string objects. Based on what I know, using String objects isn't really good memory wise for the microcontroller because of memory issues, hence, I try to work around char arrays instead and only have the string for Serial input.

I would like to ask, is this a good way of copying a char array (essentially a string) to a 2D array of multiple strings?

```
char validID[][12] = {"XX XX XX XX"};       

String word;
char data[12];
Serial.println("Enter word: ");
if(Serial.available() > 0){
    word = Serial.readString();
}
word.toCharArray(data, 12); //converts String to char array
strcpy(validID[1],data); //trying to store a new string to index 1 of validID array
```

Initially I opt to just create a function and copy each byte to the other array, though I thought maybe predefined functions would save memory in my sketch. Should I go to that kind of method instead?

Comment: The definition `char validID[][12] = {"XX XX XX XX"};` is equivalent to `char validID[1][12] = {"XX XX XX XX"};` Which means `validID[1]` will be out of bounds. Arrays in C++ (which the Arduino is programmed in) doesn't have dynamic arrays.

Comment: No, this is not the "proper way". C++ does not work this way. There is no "index 1" of the array. There's only index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Serial input immediately into the target. If you have multiple IDs (all of the same text length) and you want to avoid dynamic memory, you should define the max amount of elements beforehand.

```
typedef char IDText[12]; 

IDText validID[4]; // four texts, (11+1)char each

bool getID(IDText& id) {
  // returns true if input is valid
  if (Serial.available() >0) {
    byte idx=0;
    while (-1 != (id[idx] = Serial.read()) ) {
      if (idx < sizeof(IDText)-1) idx++; 
      delay(2); // wait for next char @9600 
    }
    id[idx] = 0; 
    return true; // demo: no other checks here
  }
  return false; // no input available
}

//include Streaming out
template<class T> inline Print& operator<< (Print &obj, T arg) { obj.print(arg); return obj; }
const char endl {'\n'};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial << F("Start: ") << __FILE__ << endl; 
}

void loop() {
  static byte idNr = 0;
  if (idNr < 4)
    if ( getID(validID[idNr]) ) {
      idNr++;
      Serial << "Got " << idNr << " validIDs now: " << endl;
      for (byte i = 0; i < idNr; i++) Serial << "  " << validID[i] << endl;
      Serial << " ------------- " << endl;
    }
}
```